# Why does this WPF slider throw an exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider

Code:

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            updateTickCounter(slider1.Value);
        }

        private void updateTickCounter(double value)
        {
            tickCounter.Content = value.ToString();
        }
```

XAML:

```
<Slider Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,21,61,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Orientation="Horizontal" TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Value="1" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" />
```

I'm trying to have a slider that starts at value 1 out of 10. Every time the slider is moved I want a label called 'tickCounter' to change text.

The code above throws an exception when ran -- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

However, once I change both the values of "Value" and "Minimum" in XAML it works fine. It's as if I can't make it not start at zero. It's really weird. Any help?

Comment: Can you find at exactly which line of code you get the exception? Is it in the code behind or during page generation? Can you show us the stack trace? Cheers!

Comment: It happens at tickCounter.Content = value.ToString(); line.

Comment: http://pastie.org/2958483

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not having read the comment before. I hoped I would get email notifications but it's disabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look on stack trace provided, then only possible reason of nullexception seems to me is that tickCounter==null

Comment: Yes, and that is probably because the slider is initialized earlier than the label, so the event fires and the label is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using events to update the label, use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

```
<Slider Name="slider1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="1" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" />

<Label Name="tickCounter" Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1"} />
```

Also, if you do not need any of the additional abilities of a `Label` you should use a `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock Name="tickCounter" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1"} />
```